# Стили для шапки

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, table, стилизация

Есть таблица

```html
<table class="calltable" id="calltable">
  <!--Заголовок таблицы-->
  <tr>
    <td>
      №
    </td>
    <td>
      Дата/Время
    </td>
    <td>
      Входящий абонент
    </td>
    <td>
      Телефон входящего абонента
    </td>
    <td>
      Исходящий абонент
    </td>
    <td>
      Телефон исходящего абонента
    </td>
    <td>
      Продолжительность
    </td>
    <td>
      Оператор абонента
    </td>
    <td>
      Стоимость вызова
    </td>
  </tr>

  <!--Получение данных из базы данных и отображение их в таблице-->



  <?php
        $hostname="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $dbname="dbcall";


        $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn === false) {
            die("Ошибка: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        } 
        else {
            $result = mysqli_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM `calls`" );
if($result) {

<!--Получение строк из базы данных и отображение их на экране в таблице-->

  ...
    echo $phptable;
                }
        }
```

Как задать цвет первой строки таблицы (шапки) `#calltable`? Я использовал `th`, но не помогло. Может я что-то делал не так, подскажите как правильно использовать `th` (если можно, то с примером) или какой-нибудь другой способ задания цвета шапки таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример, вам не помогло th потому, что у вас его нет в верстке

```css
table tr:first-child{
background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table class="calltable" id="calltable">
  <!--Заголовок таблицы-->
  <tr>
    <td>
      №
    </td>
    <td>
      Дата/Время
    </td>
    <td>
      Входящий абонент
    </td>
    <td>
      Телефон входящего абонента
    </td>
    <td>
      Исходящий абонент
    </td>
    <td>
      Телефон исходящего абонента
    </td>
    <td>
      Продолжительность
    </td>
    <td>
      Оператор абонента
    </td>
    <td>
      Стоимость вызова
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      1111
    </td>
    <td>
      1111
    </td>
    <td>
      2222
    </td>
    <td>
      2222
    </td>
    <td>
     1111
    </td>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
     1
    </td>
    <td>
     1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: и вместо того чтобы привести верстку в к виду `thead-tr-th` вы решили оставить как есть?

Answer (score 0):

А лучше таки использовать th и всё полагающееся, например, так:

```css
td, th {
  padding: 10px 3px;
}
th {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table class="calltable" id="calltable">
  <!--Заголовок таблицы-->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        №
      </th>
      <th>
        Дата/Время
      </th>
      <th>
        Входящий абонент
      </th>
      <th>
        Телефон входящего абонента
      </th>
      <th>
        Исходящий абонент
      </th>
      <th>
        Телефон исходящего абонента
      </th>
      <th>
        Продолжительность
      </th>
      <th>
        Оператор абонента
      </th>
      <th>
        Стоимость вызова
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        3
      </td>
      <td>
        4
      </td>
      <td>
        5
      </td>
      <td>
        6
      </td>
      <td>
        7
      </td>
      <td>
        8
      </td>
      <td>
        9
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table
```